# Views doesn't like multiple entity references in my entity

Tags: 8, views

I have a couple of custom entities defined by my module against plain tables in my database (because I have a lot of data and don't want to unpack it all into fields).

My **contact** entity has a entity_reference field to my **subject** entity with unlimited cardinality:

```
$fields['subjects'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
                    ->setLabel(t('Subjects'))
                    ->setSetting('target_type', 'pw_subject')
                    ->setCardinality(BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
                    ->setdisplayOptions('view', array(
                      'type' => 'entity_reference_entity_label'))
                    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
                      'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete'));
```

The **subject** entity is very simple with just id and name fields.

This causes the Entity API to create a join table and it all seems to work with regular node viewing and editing.  However when I try to add a relationship in view a view based on contact to subjects I get an SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pw_contact__subjects.subjects' in 'on clause': SELECT pw_contact.id AS id, pw_subject_pw_contact__subjects.id AS pw_subject_pw_contact__subjects_id FROM {pw_contact} pw_contact LEFT JOIN {pw_contact__subjects} pw_contact__subjects ON pw_contact.id = pw_contact__subjects.entity_id AND pw_contact__subjects.deleted = :views_join_condition_0 LEFT JOIN {pw_subject} pw_subject_pw_contact__subjects ON pw_contact__subjects.subjects = pw_subject_pw_contact__subjects.id LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:views_join_condition_0] => 0 )
```

It looks seems views is looking for a *subjects* column rather than the *subjects_target_id* that it should use - it seems to think this is a value field rather than a reference?

Anyway I'm a bit lost in the code trying to work out what's going on so any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a views bug.  See my question where I have posted a workaround: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213461/add-cardinality-unlimited-taxonomy-reference-to-custom-entity/213575#213575

Comment: I opened a drupal core issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2795455